# Is there a SDK for SugarCRM?

Tags: sdk, sugarcrm

Is there a SDK for SugarCRM ? If so does anybody knows the place to download that ?

Comment: Do you mean this ? http://support.sugarcrm.com/01_Get_Started/02_Administrators/02_Community_Edition/01_Installation_and_Setup#Download

Comment: No, Our requirement is to access SugarCRM SOAP API as we are using java. What we want is a SDK to access SugarCRM using java.

Comment: check [`Sugar Developer Guide 6.5 > Application Framework > Web Services`](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework#Web_Services)

Comment: If we are to use the wsdl and generate the client stubs,it is not possible to support backward compatibility for different versions of SugarCRM. That's why we search for the SDK though it can be done with the wsdl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulled out from the comments, check out the SOAP/REST Web Services documentation.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework#Web_Services

Comment: Please refer the comment reply. We are in need of implementing that has backward compatibility with the changes in the version of SugarCRM and it is not possible when we generate client stubs using wsdl2java.

Comment: The Web Services API has backward compatibility to support past versions of Sugar. Check out this blog post for more details on the versions of the API out there http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2010/12/21/explaination-of-all-of-the-sugar-web-services-apis-available/

Comment: Thank you jmetric for you reference.

Comment: Hi jemtric, Under the services directory there are two API's as v4 and v4_1 (at /service/v4/ and /service/v4_1/ ). So as developers which one should we use?

Comment: v4_1, and I've updated the matrix at http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2010/12/21/explaination-of-all-of-the-sugar-web-services-apis-available/ to reflect that.